# selecting children selector for older browser?

Tags: jquery, css

This ( `>` selector) will be supported up to IE9 :

```
.cc > *{
/* css style */
}
```

What can I use for older browser (IE6, IE7, IE8)?

I tried `$('.cc').children()` but seems not to be supported?

Comment: Use       .cc gt *{
/* css style */
}

Comment: it is [supported from IE7](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors#Browser_compatibility)

Comment: $('.cc') should work. jQuery requires IE6+

Comment: @szpic Depends on the version. From 2.0, old IE support got dropped.

Comment: @kapa Which kinda makes the whole premise of jQuery bridging the gap between browser versions completely ruined, but hey, jQuery never did make much sense to me XD If you don't know [Vanilla JS](http://vanilla-js.com/), you shouldn't use an advanced tool like jQuery, and if you do know Vanilla JS... well then you don't *need* jQuery...

Comment: @kapa Yeah you are right. In 1.x should work. But we don't know his version of jQ

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol They still develop the 1.x line as well which keeps the support - I use that one when I need to support oldies and it is great for that purpose. Other than that, I don't use jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure `>` has been around since IE6, actually.

EDIT: Correction: IE7. IE6 didn't have that particular selector. But if we spend hours caring about IE6, we'll never get anything done.